# awk + filter Log files

Tags: linux, perl, bash, awk, sed

I used the following nice awk command in order to filter duplicate lines

**example:**

```
cat LogFile | awk '!seen[$0]++'
```

the problem is that in some cases we need to filter duplicate lines in spite some fields are different and they no so important

for example

**LogFile:**

```
 [INFO],[02/Jun/2014-19:30:45],EXE,ds1a,INHT VERION , 1.4.4.3-08
 [INFO],[02/Jun/2014-19:31:25],EXE,ds1a,INHT VERION , 1.4.4.3-08
 [INFO],[02/Jun/2014-19:32:40],EXE,ds1a,INHT VERION , 1.4.4.3-08
```

please take a look on this  file - **LogFile**

I need to remove the duplicate lines from the third delimiter "**,**" until the end of the line ,

and no matter what is before the third delimiter

so finally I should  get this filtered file: ( should get always the first one in the list )

```
    [INFO],[02/Jun/2014-19:30:45],EXE,ds1a,INHT VERION , 1.4.4.3-08
```

so please help me to complete my task

how to filter the LofFile from the third delimiter "**,**" , and ignore the fields: **[INFO],[...........],EXE,**

Remark – implantation can be also with perl one liner line

Comment: That is a poor example because all of the records are the same. Please show how you could have different records that still need filtering out.

Comment: @maihabunash Do you still need the 3 unreferenced fields in the output?

Comment: yes , as the question asked, any way I think I will coose the Ed answer - he have exelent solution -:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With GNU awk for gensub():

```
$ awk '!seen[gensub(/([^,]*,){3}/,"","")]++' file
[INFO],[02/Jun/2014-19:30:45],EXE,ds1a,INHT VERION , 1.4.4.3-08
```

With any awk that supports RE intervals (most modern awks):

```
$ awk '{key=$0; sub(/([^,]*,){3}/,"",key)} !seen[key]++' file
[INFO],[02/Jun/2014-19:30:45],EXE,ds1a,INHT VERION , 1.4.4.3-08
```

Comment: Ah, if only you'd had 1 more cup of coffee, the glory could have been all yours :-).

Comment: I had 5 and you still stole my thunder! `:P`

Comment: Probably if I hadn't gone for coffee break I would have read this question earlier :)

Comment: Really amazing what you did here , WOW - You deserve a very high score

Comment: I Hope members will Vote for me also -:)

Comment: Wish granted :-). Also, I added a gawk-specific version, just in case that's what you're using and are happy with gawk-specific solutions (I usually am).

Comment: Sheesh, and people complain about Perl!

Comment: They don't just complain about it, they draw cartoons about it :-) http://www.zoitz.com/archives/13

Comment: thx Ed , I used your second option , and it run like a charm , I think you deserv more High score for your exelent solution

Answer (score 2):

Using a perl one-liner:

```
perl -lne '$k = s/(.*?,){3}//r; print if !$seen{$k}++' file.log
```

Outputs:

```
[INFO],[02/Jun/2014-19:30:45],EXE,ds1a,INHT VERION , 1.4.4.3-08
```

#### Explanation:

**Switches**:

- `-l`: Enable line ending processing.  (*Only needed if last line of log file is missing the new line*)
- `-n`: Creates a `while(<>){..}` loop for each line in your input file.
- `-e`: Tells `perl` to execute the code on command line.

**Code**:

- `$k = s/(.*?,){3}//r`: Save everything after the third comma in the variable `$k`
- `print if !$seen{$k}++`: Print the line if the key is not seen before.

Comment: I was foolishly trying to use a array slice as a key to a hash.  Which won't work the way I was doing it.

Comment: It will work without `-l`, as long as the final line of the log file isn't missing the new line.

Comment: `$h{"x", "y"}` should work, if it wasn't deprecated in the mean time (last decade?)

Comment: `$seen{$k}++ or print` for `unless` haters :)

Comment: Aye, that will work.  But `$h{@a[2..4]}` will just use the count as the key.  And yes jaypal, my brain just doesn't like `unless` unless it's in a paragraph and not code.  =)

Comment: Ah yes, didn't notice that.

Comment: Would `if (!$seen{$k}++) print` be too little obfuscation for a perl script :-) ?

Comment: @EdMorton you're missing curly braces, which makes everything too verbose for one liner :)

Comment: @Miller Thanks for the comments, they help a lot. What does the `r` at the end of the substitution command (`s/(.*?,){3}//r`) do? Actually - what the heck is that RE `.*?,` describing too?

Comment: @EdMorton It is a simple `sed` like substitution. The `?` makes it non-greedy so it does not match more than 3 text-comma pairs as specified in the curly brace. `/r` modifier returns the modified string instead of modifying the original string.

Comment: @jaypal - ah, I see, so the `?` makes the preceding RE segment match to just before the first `,` rather than just before the last `,`. So writing `.*?,` is equivalent to writing `[^,]*,` - got it! The `/r` thing makes sense too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different way using autosplit:

```
perl -aF, -ne'print unless $seen{"@F[3..$#F]"}++' logfile.txt
```

Comment: I like the switch style of using `-aF,`.  Might lean more toward `-F/,/` still, but grouping those to related switches is a good option for communicating intent.

Comment: @Miller: I understand your preference, but the `-F` option is really nice. If you use either `-Fx` or `-F/x/` then it will `split(/x/, $_, 0)` for you. So `-F,` does `split(/,/, $_, 0)` but magically `-F/` does `split(m[/], $_, 0)` so they've thought about it a lot. Also, using `-F/x/` doesn't seem in keeping with the whole idea of one-liners. I hate them to the core, but why stick with *any* standards if you're throwing away `strict` and `warnings`?

Comment: @Miller: Also, `-aFx` is the same as `-Fx`, saving even more key presses

Comment: Doing a little self-analysis, and I think my slight attachment for the `-F//` format stems from always trying to use `split //` instead of `split ''` so the code self documents that expression as a pattern and not just a literal string.  However, I agree that the shorter format has its benefits, so you might see it from time to time in some of my one-liners.  :)

Comment: @Miller: I agree with you regarding the first parameter of `split`, because `split / /` needs to be different from `split ' '`. But the command line equivalent of the latter is a simple `-a` without a `-F` at all, so I think the rules don't transfer

Comment: @jaypal Thus far, I rarely use `/r` because I believe it could potentially make code more fragile and less easy to read.  This is a one-liner though.  However, if it's a concern, it only adds 7 characters to do the full form.  `($k = $_) =~ s/(.*?,){3}//;`

Answer (score 0):

You can have:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{o=$0;$1=$2=$3=""}!seen[$0]++{print o;}' ...
```